# Dplyr Arrange Rows of a DF by their frequency in a column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a DF where I want to rearrange the rows so that the groups are listed in descending order based upon the group column:

```
x y group
3 2 z
1 1 z
2 2 z
3 3 a
1 2 a
3 3 a
1 1 b
2 2 b
2 2 b
1 1 g
1 1 g
1 1 g
1 1 g
1 1 g
```

The code that I have is the following:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% arrange(desc(group))
```

But this isn't giving me the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

We can reverse the order by doing the `arrange` first and then do the grouping

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    arrange(desc(group)) %>%
    group_by(group)
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   group [4]
#       x     y group
#   <int> <int> <chr>
# 1     3     2 z    
# 2     1     1 z    
# 3     2     2 z    
# 4     1     1 g    
# 5     1     1 g    
# 6     1     1 g    
# 7     1     1 g    
# 8     1     1 g    
# 9     1     1 b    
#10     2     2 b    
#11     2     2 b    
#12     3     3 a    
#13     1     2 a    
#14     3     3 a
```

---

If we need to arrange based on the frequency, create a  column of counts  with `add_count`, use `arrange` with values based on 'n' and remove that column

```
df %>%
   add_count(group) %>% 
   arrange(desc(n)) %>%   
   select(-n)
#    x y group
#1  1 1     g
#2  1 1     g
#3  1 1     g
#4  1 1     g
#5  1 1     g
#6  3 2     z
#7  1 1     z
#8  2 2     z
#9  3 3     a
#10 1 2     a
#11 3 3     a
#12 1 1     b
#13 2 2     b
#14 2 2     b
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), y = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), group = c("z", "z", "z", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Answer (score 2):

The combination of [`forcats::fct_infreq()`](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_inorder.html) and [`dplyr::arrange()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html) also works for you.

```r
#### To load dplyr, tibble, and forcats ####
library(tidyverse)

#### data creation ####
df <- tibble(
    x = c(3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    y = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    group = c("z", "z", "z", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g")
  )

#### data sorting ####
df %>% 
  arrange(
    fct_infreq(group),
    x
    )
```

Comment: Nice new solution.